# how to get credit and debt based on union of two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

today i faced a rather weird problem while i was coding and i really have no idea how to fix this, this is the code i wrote

```
      select kv.third_party,          --THIRD PARTY CODE
             kv.NUM_PUROR,            --PURCHASE CODE
             kv.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN   --ACCOUNT CODE
             SUM(DEBT) DEBT,
             SUM(CREDIT) CREDIT
    FROM(SELECT ACNVI.third_party,          
                ACNVI.NUM_PUROR,     
                ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN
                SUM(ACNVI.AMN_DBT_ACNVI - ACNVI.AMN_CRD_ACNVI) DEBT,
                0 CREDIT
        FROM BFS_ACCOUNT_COUVHER_ITEMS ACNVI
        WHERE TO_CHAR(ACNVI.ACVOH_DAT_DCM_ACVOH,'YYYY') BETWEEN '1990' AND '2000'
        AND SUBSTR(ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN,1,4) IN ('3102')
    GROUP BY  ACNVI.third_party,          
              ACNVI.NUM_PUROR,     
              ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN,
    SUBSTR(ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN,1,4)
    HAVING SUM(ACNVI.AMN_DBT_ACNVI - ANCVI.AMN_CRD_ACNVI)>0
    UNION 
    SELECT ACNVI.third_party,          
                ACNVI.NUM_PUROR,     
                ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN
                0 DEBT,
                SUM(ACNVI.AMN_CRD_ACNVI- ACNVI.AMN_DBT_ACNVI ) CREDIT
        FROM BFS_ACCOUNT_COUVHER_ITEMS ACNVI
        WHERE TO_CHAR(ACNVI.ACVOH_DAT_DCM_ACVOH,'YYYY') BETWEEN '1990' AND '2000'
        AND SUBSTR(ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN,1,4) IN ('3102')
    GROUP BY  ACNVI.third_party,          
                ACNVI.NUM_PUROR,     
                ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN,
    SUBSTR(ACNVI.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN,1,4)
    HAVING SUM(ACNVI.AMN_CRD_ACNVI- ACNVI.AMN_DBT_ACNVI)>0) KV
*****
    GROUP BY KV.THIRD_PART,KV.NUM_PUROR,KV.DTACN_COD_ACN_DTACN
```

ok so the above is the code i wrote and what i want which i dunno how to do is this: i want to have something like below in the star area
"having sum(debt)=sum(credit)"
but when i write that the table will be empty.

parameter meanings:

```
#amn_dbt_acnvi   --- amount of debt for each account
#amn_crd_acnvi   --- amount of credit for each account
#(amn_dbt_acnvi-amn_crd_acnvi)    --- account balance (i wrote two kinds in the code because i want to have one balance on debt and one balance on credit)
#bfs_account_voucher_items   ---this is the table with required info (debt,credit,third_party code ,etc.)

    needed result is something like this for example :
    row#1 : third_party: a // num_puror: b//account_code: 310201//debt : 100 credit :0
    row#2 : third_party: a // num_puror: b//account_code: 310203//debt : 0 
credit:100
```

subtract of them should be 0

Comment: Please add table structures, data set and wished result set

Comment: table is too huge to add but i want a result like this

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: is it that bad? i mean the data could be anything but its obvious that i want to get account with 3102 as their number and apply the code on them

Comment: Post a part of your table ;)

Comment: but im not at work~ T___T